# Cange export sort order in JabRef

Tags: sorting, jabref, export

I use JabRef to create my bibliography in LaTeX. When there are more than one references from a same author, I would like them to be ordered chronologically. However, the order is alphabetical, according to the titles, although I changed it in JabRef, under Options - Preferences - Export sort order, as is explained here:

[Export - JabRef](https://docs.jabref.org/collaborative-work/export)

This has no effect in my LaTeX document. Do you have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: The order in the bibliography file produced by JabRef (with the `.bib` extension) is independent from the order of the references in the pdf produced by LaTeX. The order in the pdf is determined by the bibliography style that you use. This style is indicated in the code of your document. There are hundreds of different styles with various orders, such as alphabetical then chronological, or only chronological, or in the order of where they are referenced in the document, etc. See https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management for a general introduction.

Comment: Many thanks! How do I find out the bibliography style such that the order is alphabetical and then chronological? And how do I write this in the preamble?

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434945/biblatex-reference-sorting-in-same-first-author-different-year-entries is a good starting point.

Comment: For the record: this is not about JabRef (JabRef just an editor of the bib(la)tex). The issue is with LaTeX and bib(la)tex.

Comment: Thank you for your help!